# Sqllite or shared preferences to persist the changes

Tags: android

I have a scenario where upon clicking on a button, i need to show/hide an `listView`. I have a `Activity` which holds 12 `ListViews`, if the user hides 5 `listViews`, then for that entire session until he log's out of app, the acitvity should show only 5 `ListViews`.

In this situation how would i carry out the operation, should i save the checked value in a sqllite and read it each time when the user opens that activity or should i go with some other approach. How would it impact the performance of the `application`.

Comment: shared preferences is best i think..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very short answer i think.

If your data are **structured** for example you want to store whole objects so right approach would be to use `SQLite` It's worth to mention that this requires to write a little more source code(implement subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper and CRUD operations).

But in your case i think an usage of [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) is enough. It provides very lightweight solution that will make a trick.

Comment: @Kevin man, now im very busy - i need to finish my application for bachelor thesis and also finish its documentation :-

Comment: College days are always fun and assignments are always bottleneck, i remember those days.. last minute preparation, submission etc etc...

Answer (score 1):

Working with a SQLite database would be rather arbitrary for saving settings, not to mention relativly slow. I would recommend using the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) class for storing settings.

Comment: Slow is a relative term. While I agree that `SharedPreferences` is the better way, I would find it hard to believe that storing settings in `SQLite` would be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is too little. Therefore, I would suggest you to go with `SharedPreferences` because its light and easy to use without too much extra code.

SQLIte is fine too but its too much hassle in your scenario because then you need to setup `SQLiteOpenHelper` and prepare queries for that.